# How to send a form field in a ribbon button command definition?

Tags: forms, button, dynamics-crm-2011, customization, ribbon

I'm creating a new button in the account ribbon, I need to pass a form field to my webresource.

This is my progress so far:

```
<CommandDefinition Id="MyTest.Account.Form.CommandDefinition">
    <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.Enabled" />
    </EnableRules>
    <DisplayRules />
    <Actions>
        <Url Address="$webresource:new_/TestPage.html" PassParams="true"></Url>
    </Actions>
</CommandDefinition>
```

This works fine but "PassParams" only sends the record Id, I need to pass other data fields like the account name and so. 
I searched online but I couldn't find a complete example for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the CrmParameter you want to pass:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309332.aspx

Although, I prefer calling a JavaScript function to get the parameters needed and open the URL.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334432.aspx

Either should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm still confused about it. The CrmParameter only has predefined values for "Value" which I can retrieve, but how can I retrieve a custom field value "new_customfield" from the current opened account form ? Can you write me an example to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Rest Javascript, like RetrieveRecord when you press the created button on the ribbon. So you'll be able to get a value of your field.